# custom float from sqlite -> UIButton.frame CGRectMake

Tags: iphone, sqlite

is it possible to load a float value out of an internal sqlite database and use it as a variable in CGMakeRect from UIButton?

I can't get this to work :-(

Here is some of my code. Maybe someone knows how to deal with this prob!!!

```
self.positionX = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(float)sqlite3_column_double(init_statement, 3)];
// other class:
imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(positionX , 100.0, 37.0, 37.0);
```

The "linking" works just fine. But I get an error saying: "Incompatible type for argument.."

My types are:

- sqlite positionX as FLOAT
- postionX as CGFloat

Does someone have a solution for my problem???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should get float value from NSNumber object:

```
imageButton.frame = CGRectMake([positionX floatValue] , 100.0, 37.0, 37.0);
```